# jQuery counter that submits a form after some time: How to grab the current value in order to submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I want to show a counter in jQuery that when it reaches 10 minutes it submits a form.

Here's my counter in html:

```
<span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span>
```

And here is the jQuery that I'm doing (I do have the counter but I don't know how to retrieve the value of it in order to do something, as I've tried with val() but all I get is an empty string):

```
var sec = 0;
 function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
 setInterval( function(){
 var segundos = $("#seconds").html(pad(++sec%60));

 var minutos = $("#minutes").html(pad(parseInt(sec/60,10)));
}, 1000);
```

Here's the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Rosamunda/pen/BJXYEO)

The process should be that after the counter reaches 10 minutes, .submit() fires up in the form, but how do I get the value of the counter?

If I do `console.log(minutos);` nothing shows up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval(...)` will fire the code inside its function every X miliseconds.  So no need to check the value, just put your submit inside it.  However it will happen every 10 minutes, not just once.  I would use set timeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#myForm').submit() }, 60000 * 10);
```

That will submit a form with ID 'myForm' after 10 minutes.